# Can i increase the number of visible open file tabs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I'm using Eclipse Indigo, currently only 6 open file tab is visible at a time, if i open more then they stay open but file appear in drop down list and get out of visibility.
  Is it possible to configure to show at least 10 open and visible file on the Tabs.
Thanks,Rahul.

Comment: Double click on one of the tabs to minimize the other views.  You may not get 10, but you'll get more than 6 visible tabs.

Comment: Double Click does nothing in my case I'm using it in Linux box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visible tabs on eclipse are determined by the width of the area, the larger area you have more tabs you can see ...

Comment: You can minimize the outline view to get a few more.  Because the tabs follow a random appear-disappear order, you could always opt for 1 tab :-)  It's a preference in `Preferences>General>Editors` called "Show multiple editor tabs". Then you can use CTRL+E or CTRL+SHIFT+E to switch editors

Comment: Yes i already have that option check, all i wish to see is firefox or chrome like tab arrangements.